# JAVA: MouseDragged Event Precision

Tags: java, mousemotionevent

While setting up a dynamic component in my program, I noticed that there was some flickering whenever the component (a JPanel) was relocated. So, I printed the mouse position at each drag event using:

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e.getX());
}
```

And it came out with some interesting results. With normal-speed drag from left to right, I got the following output in the console:

```
49
47
...
55
53
58
56
61
59
64
62
67
65
70
65
73
68
76
71
79
74
...
97
92
100
95
103
95
106
```

You'll notice the numbers fluctuate up then down as the tracking proceeds. I've fixed this before by throwing some math at it, but it now I'm wondering why and how I can make it work normally. Are certain `MouseEvents` processed before their event predecessors?

Comment: I think mouse speed will affect this result, as if you move the mouse slowly, you see the increasing will be one each time.

Comment: Au contraire, I get the same results no matter what speed I move the mouse at. Are you running a successful model of this?

Comment: Yes, the result was like what I said.

Comment: For my model numbers are also quite sequential. I suppose something is wrong with the mouse you're using or something in your app is generating additional events.

Comment: Interesting. I am using a gaming mouse with custom dpi settings. Could that be it?